# How to set time for screen lock Android Java ?? (Android 10)

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, lockscreen

I'm create a lock screen app normal but only start lock by time set in TimePickerDialog. I'm try to starting the lockService when AlarmManager wakeup by broadcast but the result i get is i have to restart the app for the lock screen to work. Is there a way to automatically lock the screen when the time is set when my app is destroyed?Of course, the message will be displayed. My app work on Android 10.
This is my set time

```
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        setAlarm(calendar);
        updateTimeText(calendar);
    }
    private void setAlarm(Calendar calendar ) {
        if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE , 1);
        }

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("countdown","on");
//        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, BackgroundManager.class);
//        long test = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
//        intent2.putExtra("time",test);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            //alarm 1L
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            //Alarm everyday
//                alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
//                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
```

This is BroadcastReceiver to startService

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    //    private CountdownTimer myService;
//    private boolean isConnected;
    private final static String TAG = "AlarmReceiver BroadcastService";
                    BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(LockSettingActivity.this).stopService(LockService.class);
                    BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(LockSettingActivity.this).startService(LockService.class);
                  BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(LockSettingActivity.this).startAlarmManager();
}
```

This is class to Lock

```
public class LockService extends IntentService {

    public static final String UNLOCK_ACTION = "UNLOCK_ACTION";
    public static final String LOCK_SERVICE_LASTTIME = "LOCK_SERVICE_LASTTIME";
    public static final String LOCK_SERVICE_LASTAPP = "LOCK_SERVICE_LASTAPP";
    private static final String TAG = "LockService";
    public static boolean isActionLock = false;
    public boolean threadIsTerminate = false;
    @Nullable
    public String savePkgName;
    UsageStatsManager sUsageStatsManager;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    //private boolean isLockTypeAccessibility;
    private long lastUnlockTimeSeconds = 0;
    private String lastUnlockPackageName = "";
    private boolean lockState;
    private ServiceReceiver mServiceReceiver;
    private CommLockInfoManager mLockInfoManager;
    private boolean lockState2;

    @Nullable
    private ActivityManager activityManager;

    public LockService() {
        super("LockService");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        lockState = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_STATE);
        mLockInfoManager = new CommLockInfoManager(this);
        activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        lockState2 = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.Alarm_Receiver);
        mServiceReceiver = new ServiceReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(UNLOCK_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mServiceReceiver, filter);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            sUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        }

        threadIsTerminate = true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationUtil.createNotification(this, "Now Sleep", "NowSleep running in background");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            runForever();
    }

    private void runForever() {
        while (threadIsTerminate) {
            String packageName = getLauncherTopApp(LockService.this, activityManager);
            if (lockState && !TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName) && !inWhiteList(packageName)) {
                boolean isLockOffScreenTime = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_AUTO_SCREEN_TIME, false);
                boolean isLockOffScreen = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_AUTO_SCREEN, false);
                savePkgName = SpUtil.getInstance().getString(AppConstants.LOCK_LAST_LOAD_PKG_NAME, "");

                if (isLockOffScreenTime && !isLockOffScreen) {
                    long time = SpUtil.getInstance().getLong(AppConstants.LOCK_CURR_MILLISECONDS, 0);
                    long leaverTime = SpUtil.getInstance().getLong(AppConstants.LOCK_APART_MILLISECONDS, 0);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(savePkgName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName) && !savePkgName.equals(packageName)) {
                        if (getHomes().contains(packageName) || packageName.contains("launcher")) {
                            boolean isSetUnLock = mLockInfoManager.isSetUnLock(savePkgName);
                            if (!isSetUnLock) {
                                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time > leaverTime) {
                                    mLockInfoManager.lockCommApplication(savePkgName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isLockOffScreenTime && isLockOffScreen) {
                    long time = SpUtil.getInstance().getLong(AppConstants.LOCK_CURR_MILLISECONDS, 0);
                    long leaverTime = SpUtil.getInstance().getLong(AppConstants.LOCK_APART_MILLISECONDS, 0);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(savePkgName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName) && !savePkgName.equals(packageName)) {
                        if (getHomes().contains(packageName) || packageName.contains("launcher")) {
                            boolean isSetUnLock = mLockInfoManager.isSetUnLock(savePkgName);
                            if (!isSetUnLock) {
                                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - time > leaverTime) {
                                    mLockInfoManager.lockCommApplication(savePkgName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (!isLockOffScreenTime && isLockOffScreen && !TextUtils.isEmpty(savePkgName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName)) {
                    if (!savePkgName.equals(packageName)) {
                        isActionLock = false;
                        if (getHomes().contains(packageName) || packageName.contains("launcher")) {
                            boolean isSetUnLock = mLockInfoManager.isSetUnLock(savePkgName);
                            if (!isSetUnLock) {
                                mLockInfoManager.lockCommApplication(savePkgName);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        isActionLock = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!isLockOffScreenTime && !isLockOffScreen && !TextUtils.isEmpty(savePkgName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName) && !savePkgName.equals(packageName)) {
                    if (getHomes().contains(packageName) || packageName.contains("launcher")) {
                        boolean isSetUnLock = mLockInfoManager.isSetUnLock(savePkgName);
                        if (!isSetUnLock) {
                            mLockInfoManager.lockCommApplication(savePkgName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (mLockInfoManager.isLockedPackageName(packageName)) {
                    passwordLock(packageName);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(210);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean inWhiteList(String packageName) {
        return packageName.equals(AppConstants.APP_PACKAGE_NAME);
    }

    public String getLauncherTopApp(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ActivityManager activityManager) {
        //isLockTypeAccessibility = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_TYPE, false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> appTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
            if (null != appTasks && !appTasks.isEmpty()) {
                return appTasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            }
        } else {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long beginTime = endTime - 10000;
            String result = "";
            UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
            UsageEvents usageEvents = sUsageStatsManager.queryEvents(beginTime, endTime);
            while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
                usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
                if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
                    result = event.getPackageName();
                }
            }
            if (!android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @NonNull
    private List<String> getHomes() {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo ri : resolveInfo) {
            names.add(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
        }
        return names;
    }

    private void passwordLock(String packageName) {

            LockApplication.getInstance().clearAllActivity();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GestureUnlockActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.LOCK_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
            intent.putExtra(AppConstants.LOCK_FROM, AppConstants.LOCK_FROM_FINISH);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        threadIsTerminate = false;
        timer.cancel();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationUtil.cancelNotification(this);
        }
        lockState = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_STATE);
        if (lockState) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LockRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("type", "lockservice");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        unregisterReceiver(mServiceReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        threadIsTerminate = false;
        timer.cancel();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationUtil.cancelNotification(this);
        }
        lockState = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_STATE);
        if (lockState) {
            Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
            restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
            PendingIntent restartPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1495, restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            myAlarmService.set(
                    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1500,
                    restartPendingIntent);
        }

    }

    public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            boolean isLockOffScreen = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_AUTO_SCREEN, false);
            boolean isLockOffScreenTime = SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_AUTO_SCREEN_TIME, false);

            switch (action) {
                case UNLOCK_ACTION:
                    lastUnlockPackageName = intent.getStringExtra(LOCK_SERVICE_LASTAPP);
                    lastUnlockTimeSeconds = intent.getLongExtra(LOCK_SERVICE_LASTTIME, lastUnlockTimeSeconds);
                    break;
                case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
                    SpUtil.getInstance().putLong(AppConstants.LOCK_CURR_MILLISECONDS, System.currentTimeMillis());

                    if (!isLockOffScreenTime && isLockOffScreen) {
                        String savePkgName = SpUtil.getInstance().getString(AppConstants.LOCK_LAST_LOAD_PKG_NAME, "");
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(savePkgName)) {
                            if (isActionLock) {
                                mLockInfoManager.lockCommApplication(lastUnlockPackageName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is class to Restart LockService

```
public class LockRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean lockState=SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_STATE);
        if (intent != null && lockState) {
            String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
            if (type.contentEquals("lockservice")){
                //context.startService(new Intent(context, LockService.class));
            BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(context).startService(LockService.class);
            }
           /* else if (SpUtil.getInstance().getBoolean(AppConstants.LOCK_TYPE, false))
                BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(context).startService(LockAccessibilityService.class);*/
            else if (type.contentEquals("startlockserviceFromAM")) {
                if (!BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(context).isServiceRunning(LockService.class)) {
                    BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(context).startService(LockService.class);
                }
                //repeat
                BackgroundManager.getInstance().init(context).startAlarmManager();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please give me instructions, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this?

Comment: i had to run device-admin-owner with adb-shell command for it to work. But is there a way without having to do this?